# Thumbnail not showing when sharing on FB and WhatsApp?

Tags: wordpress, thumbnails, meta-tags, yoast

I have a WordPress site installed with Yoast SEO. I have checked that it has the necessary open graph tags but my image is still not showing when being shared.

`<meta property="og:title" content="Home"> <meta property="og:type" content="website"> <meta property="og:url" content="https://www.fixics.com/"> <meta property="og:image" content="https://www.fixics.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/fixicslogoNormalRect.jpg">`

Can advise what am I missing?

**UPDATE**
This is the debug i got from FB.

Provided og:image, https://www.fixics.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/fixicslogoNormalRect.jpg could not be downloaded. This can happen due to several different reasons such as your server using unsupported content-encoding. The crawler accepts deflate and gzip content encodings.

i have search through online and did multiple of **scraping** but still image are unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have configured the Graph metadata of your Yoast Plugin, if your ans is no, then follow this navigation> WordPress Dashboard » Left Side Menu » SEO » Social » Facebook » Enable Open Graph metadata » Add Facebook App ID.

Scenario 2: If you have done that, and still facing the problem then you need to debug your web page. Here is the guideline: Go to  Open Graph Debugger page and debug your page. Just paste your website’s link in the blank field and press the Debug Button. Wait for the result. If you don’t get the result then click Scrape Again Button. [Screenshot.](http://prntscr.com/of5372)

Hopefully, you will get your desired result from here. But if you still facing problem then you can check this details guideline from [here.](https://gtarafdar.com/blog/how-to-add-thumbnail-image-in-link/)

Comment: Hi, I did a debug and able to see the thumbnail image.

Comment: I realised that disabling Yoast SEO plugin and the sharing on whatsapp thumbnail able to display. whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and in my case it was the image name, it had uppercase letters. When I removed it, renaming the file, it worked.